# Why the Crystal Report didn't show up

Tags: c#, vba, crystal-reports, vb6

Why the crystal report didn't show up? I already breakpoint and check line by line and already passed to the CrystalReport1.PrintReport.

What is the possible cause of this? I checked the path it's correct.

[image]

```
If dbcboReport = "Account Balances Summary" Then
        Call Update_Sql
        CrystalReport1.ReportFileName = App.Path & "\..\Rpt\Cs_Bbg_TrxBal_Summary.rpt"
        CrystalReport1.PrintReport
        DoEvents
        cmdOk.Enabled = True
        cmdCancel.Enabled = True
        lblStatus.Caption = ""
        lblStatus.Refresh
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: Do you mean that no file is being generated?  Is the path valid? I would copy the entire full path from the debugger and paste into Windows Explorer, make sure it works.

Comment: Also, what is the `On Error` setting for your code? If it is `On Error Resume Next` then maybe an error has occurred which is being ignored.

Comment: @StayOnTarget yes, the path works but it still didn't show up